# Scala - How to return a Map value by function?

Tags: scala

Why below function is not work in scala?

```
def getUpdatedMap(keywords: String, m: Map[String, String]) : Map[String, String] = {
  m += (keywords -> "abcde")
}
```

> Compilation error:
>   value += is not a member of Map[String, String]

I'm quite new in Scala, any thing I have forget to define or missing?
Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are confusing the [immutable `Map`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.collection.immutable.Map) and the [mutable `Map`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.collection.mutable.Map).

```
// import mutable map as MutableMap
import scala.collection.mutable.{Map => MutableMap}

val mmap = MutableMap("a" -> 1)
mmap += "b" -> 2 // mutates original map
// mmap = Map(b -> 2, a -> 1)

// use immutable map
val imap = Map("c" -> 3)
val updatedIMap = imap.updated("d", 4) // returns a new updated immutable map
// imap = Map("c" -> 3)
// updateIMap = Map(c -> 3, d -> 4)
```

Answer (score 7):

You're not missing anything, exactly. `Map` just doesn't have a `+=` method, as the compiler said. Check out [the API docs](http://scala-lang.org/files/archive/api/current/index.html#scala.collection.Map).

I think the method you want here is `+`.

> `def +[B1 >: B](kv: (A, B1)): Map[A, B1]`
>
> Adds key/value pairs to this map, returning a new map.

```
def getUpdatedMap(keywords: String, m: Map[String, String]):
  Map[String, String] = m + (keywords -> "abcde")
```

Answer (score 2):

As everyone else said, immutable `Map` has no `+=` method. Just want to add that maybe you confused it with compiler's shortcut for `var`s:

```
scala> var a = Map(1 -> 1)
a: scala.collection.immutable.Map[Int,Int] = Map(1 -> 1)

scala> a += 2 -> 2

scala> a
res2: scala.collection.immutable.Map[Int,Int] = Map(1 -> 1, 2 -> 2)
```

This `+=` shortcut is the same as `a = a + 2 -> 2`, so it won't work for immutable values, like input parameters:

```
scala> def getMutated(m: Map[Int, Int]) = {m = m + (1 -> 1)}
   <console>:7: error: reassignment to val
       def getMutated(m: Map[Int, Int]) = {m = m + (1 -> 1)}
                                             ^
```

You could declare a `var` inside your function, however the best and simplest way is to use `+` as someone else said.

Answer (score 0):

It's exactly what it says: you are calling the method `+=` on `m`, which is a `Map`, but `Map` doesn't have a `+=` method.

It's not quite clear to me what you are trying to achieve here, from the looks of it, this seems to be what you want:

```
def getUpdatedMap(keywords: String, m: Map[String, String]) = 
  m + (keywords -> "abcde")
```